I can't post a question on Stack Overflow as it thinks it's spam
Here are some screenshots of the question I'm trying to post:


Why is Stack Overflow blocking it for being spam?

Judging from your screenshots, your question is quite long and contains a lot of code. Are you certain that all of that code is necessary in order to replicate the issue you're having? Questions on Stack Overflow require minimal reproducible examples, i.e. only the absolute bare minimum required to replicate the issue. Reducing the amount of code in your question should allow you to post it without issue.

@F1Krazy not sure. Spam block doesn't mind the amount of code afaik, it just look for suspicious links, and such a link is indeed part of the question, and what likely triggered the spam alert. The answer already mention this as well, so after removing it, other quality filters might kick in but otherwise, no spam.


Why is Stack Overflow blocking it for being spam?

Because the RegEx that is used to verify content concludes it is.
These are the things you minimally need to address:

length: we don't need the back story, just an Minimal Reproducible Example.
proper domains: get rid of all the .---.com domains. If you need to obfuscate a domain, use example.com.
remove punctuation: domains don't need to be in backticks, urls to images don't need to be in parenthesis
Add blank lines: before and after a code block a blank line helps separating  blocks
reduce use of inline markup: we don't need emphasis like that

If all this still doesn't make it pass the quality gate then copy everything out and add it back paragraph by paragraph, checking each time whether you pass or not. That will narrow down which block of text is triggering the quality gate.
